# pgfplots: stacked plots using absolute values instead of relative

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to use absolute coordinates instead of relative values when using a ybar stacked plot. Is this possible? I know I can just reformat my data to be relative, but it sounds like pgfplots could do that job too. I assume my real problem is that what I seek is not 'stacked', but just 'overlay'. Does that exist?

Here is an example from converting an area plot that uses absolute coordinates to a ybar stacked plot to show what I mean.

[image: area plot]

```
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[area style,xtick=data]
\addplot[red,fill=red] coordinates { (1,8) (2,8) (3,9) (4,10) } \closedcycle;
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates { (1,5) (2,7) (3,8) (4,9)  } \closedcycle;
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates { (1,3) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8)  } \closedcycle;
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Original area plot ordered back to front using absolute values that I want to convert to a stacked bar plot instead.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: stacked relative]

```
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,xtick=data]
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates { (1,3) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8) };
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates { (1,2) (2,2) (3,1) (4,1) };
\addplot[red,fill=red] coordinates { (1,3) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) };
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Stacked using base values and relative values, ordered bottom to top. This is the output I desire, but I had to modify the data to be relative.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: stacked_absolute]

```
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,xtick=data]
\addplot[red,fill=red] coordinates { (1,8) (2,8) (3,9) (4,10) };
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates { (1,5) (2,7) (3,8) (4,9)  };
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates { (1,3) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8)  };
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Stacked using original absolute data, ordered back to front.}
\end{figure}
```

As a new user I can't make new keywords, but I wish they were:
pgfplots, stacked, ybar, absolute, relative.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! We don't want to go overboard with tags (keywords) -- e.g., `absolute` and `relative` aren't particularly helpful when looking for relevant questions. (And I'm sure that `pgfplots` is sufficient as a call to the experts. `;-)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay the bars by setting `bar shift=0pt`. Note that you should also always set `ymin=0` explicitly to make sure the whole columns are visible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar shift=0pt,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data]
\addplot[red,fill=red] coordinates { (1,8) (2,8) (3,9) (4,10) };
\addplot[green,fill=green] coordinates { (1,5) (2,7) (3,8) (4,9)  };
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] coordinates { (1,3) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8)  };
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Stacked using original absolute data, ordered back to front.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```